# twitter bootstrap bind select to input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I'm completely confused by the jargon of Bootstrap.  I'm creating a page where I select a "specialty" from a select and I want to bind that selection to what used to be CFDIV but I can't use that any more.  If the user selects Fed/Gen as a specialty then I want to show all of the sub-specialties for that group.

```
<div style="width:95">Specialty:
  <select enabled="Yes" name="specialty" multiple="no" required="Yes" message="Specialty is Required.">
     <option value = "1" <cfif QUser.specialty EQ "1">selected</cfif>>Fed / Gen</option>
     <option value = "2" <cfif QUser.specialty EQ "2">selected</cfif>>State & Local</option>
     <option value = "3" <cfif QUser.specialty EQ "3">selected</cfif>>International</option>
     <option value = "5" <cfif QUser.specialty EQ "5">selected</cfif>>Human Resource</option>
     <option value = "6" <cfif QUser.specialty EQ "6">selected</cfif>>Other</option>
  </select></td>

</div>    
<div>
    Sub Specialties
</div>
<!---             <cfdiv id="subspecDiv" bind="url:panels/panel1_5_1.cfm?indivnum=#indivnum#&specialty_select={specialty}" /> --->
<cfif url.specialty_select neq "">
<cfif url.specialty_select NEQ "0">
    <table width="100%">  
       <cfquery name="subSpecList" datasource="#request.dsn#">
            SELECT *
            FROM Subspecialty
            WHERE specialtyID = #url.specialty_select#
            <cfif url.specialty_select EQ '3'>
            ORDER by sequence
            </cfif>
       </cfquery>

       <cfset variables.newrow = true>
       <tr>
         <cfoutput query="subSpecList">       
    <cfquery name="subSpecCheck" datasource="#request.dsn#">
               SELECT * 
           FROM users_subspecialty
           WHERE 0=0
           <cfif indivnum NEQ "">
            AND UserID = <cfqueryparam value="#indivNum#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC" maxlength="10"/>
           </cfif>
           AND subspecialtyid = #subspecialtyid#
        </cfquery>              

            <cfif variables.newrow EQ true>
                <tr> 
            </cfif>
            <td align="left" width="50%">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                        <td style="width:60"><input type="text" name="subspec_#subspecialtyid#" size="2" <cfif subSpecCheck.percentage gt "0">value="#subSpecCheck.percentage#" </cfif> onChange="javascript: experienceUpdateDate();" /> %</td>
                        <td style="width:5">
                <input type="text" name="subspecABC_#subspecialtyid#" value="#subSpecCheck.ABC#" size="1" maxlength="1" onChange="javascript: experienceUpdateDate();" /></td>
                          <td style="width:140">&nbsp;#title#</td>
                     </tr>
                   </table>
                    </td>
                <cfif subSpecList.currentRow MOD 2 EQ 0>
                    </tr>
                    <cfset variables.newrow = true>
                    <cfelse>
                    <cfset variables.newrow = false>
                    </cfif>

          </cfoutput>
      </tr>
      </table>
 </cfif>               
</cfif>
```

Comment: I'm making a few assumptions... #1 that you meant to divide your code into 2 files right below sub specialties.  #2 wrap your select statement at the top with cfform and change your select to cfselect.  and my PSA - more consistent usage of your cfqueryparam statement would help.

Comment: No, I'm converting code used in our CF based admin system to Twitter Bootstrap.  I'm eliminating tables, etc.  I'm also not using cfform and cfdiv, etc.  Mine is not to reason why... blah,blah,blah.  I need to bind the select to the "sub specialty" table. I have to convert the cfquery to cfinvoke. Or, I have Jquery available for ajax calls.

Comment: Other than your preference, this is no physcial reason why they cant work together..  your going to have to load jquery, give your select box and ID, and on the onchange of your select box, do an ajax call yo a script, passing over the ID, returning json, and then parsing the json with jquery, etc.... OR, you could keep your code the same, ans wrap the cfform and switch to cfselect.  You can still apply all the same bootstrap classes to those elements to make it look pretty.  When the page is done loading, and your looking in your browser, it all looks pretty much the same.